# Revert change to ember data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to revert a change to an Ember Data model easily?

I have a model bound to an edit view.   This view enables the user to cancel editing, at which point I'd like to revert the changes to the model.   Is there an easy way to do this without cloning all the values off the side?

Comment: `object.get('transaction').rollback()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ember Data supports the concept of transactions. We can create a transaction and assign Ember data records to them and if we want to undo the changes we can call the transactions rollback() method. Also if we do not create an explicit transaction the records are assigned to a default transaction which can be rolled back by calling the rollback() method on the DS.store object itself.

Comment: Thank you!  For completeness sake, there is a nice writeup of transactions in the Ember Data sources.  Read the comment block above the definition of DS.Transaction

Comment: The comment block for transaction also says that we can run a "commit" or "rollback" directly on the store object in case of default transaction. When I try to do a rollback, I get an error :
TypeError: Object <(subclass of DS.Store):ember1117> has no method 'rollback'
Any help with this?

Answer (score 14):

Starting from Ember Data version 2, there are not transactions anymore, but you can reset models to their last status before saved editions with:

```
model.rollbackAttributes();
```

Answer (score 5):

The name of the default transaction is named 'defaultTransaction'. In fact, when Embers commits, it uses this default transaction. I can't use directly rollback on the store directly.

Instead of using store.rollback, you should have something like:

```
store.get('defaultTransaction').rollback()
```

or (if you are in a router event manager)

```
event.get('store.defaultTransaction').rollback()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do a [rollback](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback) on the model itself if it is in an "isDirty" state.

```
this.get('model').rollback();
```

Example

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

 actions: {
    cancelEditModel: function(){

        this.get('model').rollback();

        this.transitionToRoute('...');

        return false;
    }
  }
});
```